# how to include jquery loader in angular 4.6 application?

Tags: jquery, angular

I am new to angular 4.6 and trying to show loading image in my application using jQuery but its not working. I search/try lot of code they are suggest that this is because of nested routing, is it right or what solution?

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
       $('#loader').fadeOut();
       $('#loader-wrapper').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
       $('body').delay(350).css({
           'overflow': 'visible'
       });
```

Comment: when you want to show this loader? while loading website or while some HTTPcalls? what's the error you getting?

Comment: while HTTP calls  because I have some query in the  backend which takes 30 to 40 sec to produce output and i tried angular loader but you have to start and hide the loader so i need proper solution

Comment: So why to use JQuery for this simple problem, I mean you can handle this using angular way too, if you want

Comment: I wants proper solution where i don't need to hide or start loader

Comment: But I you set manually hide/show it would be better instead of using approx. delay like you used `350` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JQuery simply use `*ngIf` like this -

```
<div id='#loader' *ngIf='loading'>Your Loader</div>

someHTTPCalls() {
  this.loading = true;

  // when HTTP finish set it to false
  this.loading = false;
}
```

Comment: @bhaumikshah Good, But I don't feel that just for loader we need to use extra plugin instead we can manage it via just angular's conditions, see my updated answer